# Make input color box larger

Tags: html, css

How do you make the `input type="color"`box larger?

Currently it is an extremely small box, and I'd like to change the dimensions of it.

[image]

Changing the height/width doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS associated with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have overridden some css style. It's working by default:

```css
input[type="color"] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an solution working in Chrome, Firefox. I haven't tested it on other browser. This rules can be overridden by browser default input appereance.

```css
input[type="color"]{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" />
```